# three sets of headphones not plugging into brand new lg optimus g phone

Tags: headphone-jack

I have 3 sets of headphones, being he exact same size. They all fit and even click into my old phone's head jack, where as with my new phone the lg optimus g they go in midway and the only way for the headphone jack to read the headphones I have to hold it in. There isn't dust in it or anything I don't know what is happening. This is ridiculous

Answer (score 2):

Take it to the shop you bought it and get them to work out what's going wrong. This isn't the sort of problem you can easily fix over the internet: you need an expert there to see what's up with the jack. In addition, if it's a common problem, the people at the shop will already have heard about it from other customers. Maybe the jack is just too tight and needs some more force, or maybe there's some fluff stuck inside where you can't see.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem with my Optimus G. If you have a case then you should take it off, then put your headphones in push down until you hear a click.

Answer (score -1):

I used a paper clip and poked it hard inside and it finally worked. It was not going in all the way, now it is!

Answer (score -2):

If you're using a smartphone case, it could be caused of it's in the way, preventing the jack to fully plug-in.

Comment: Relatively sure the questioner would have told us if she was using a case on her phone that she hadn't on the other phone, and likely wouldn't have asked the question to begin with if so.